# How to drop view if older than a day and only if it begins with certain characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, ssms, sql-server-2016

I want to drop all views from a server that were created more than 1 day ago and that begin with 'EXAMPLE_VIEW%'. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: *"How would I go about doing this?"* By using dynamic SQL. What have you tried so far? This feels a like an XY problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to generate the script from the `sys.views` catalog view with your desired criteria. The example below uses `XML PATH` for string concatenation since you are using SQL Server 2016. One can use `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server 2017 and later. This example also includes a check for the `dbo` schema, which you can tweak if needed.

```
DECLARE @DropScript nvarchar(MAX) =
    STUFF(
        (SELECT
            N';DROP VIEW ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name)
        FROM sys.views
        WHERE
            name LIKE N'WQB_VIEW%'
            AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) = N'dbo'
            AND create_date < DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DropScript;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @view TABLE(id INT identity(1,1), viewname VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @view (viewname)
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type='v' and cast(create_date AS DATE)< cast(dateadd(DY,-1,getdate()) AS DATE) 

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM @view
WHILE @count>0
BEGIN
    SELECT @name=viewname FROM @view WHERE id = @count
    SELECT @name
    EXEC('DROP VIEW '+@name+'')
    SET @count=@count-1
END
```